# Limit of cos function in a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

In my assignment I have to calculate to following limit. I wanted to know if my solution is correct. Your help is appreciated:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos\frac{\pi n} {n+1} $$

Here's my solution:

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos \pi \frac{n} {n+1} $$

Since $\frac {n} {n+1}\to 1 $ and $\cos \pi \to (-1)$ we can use the "infinity times a number" rule, since $n \to \infty$.

Therefore, the limit will be $(- \infty) $

Did I Get it right?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Yes. Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. However, we usually say its limit does not exist.

Comment: You mean minus infinity does not exist as a limit? Because it's not finite?

Comment: Just since $\infty$ is not a finite number.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos\left(\frac{\pi n} {n+1}\right) =$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n} {n+1}\right) =$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\pi n} {n+1}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\pi } {1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\cos(\pi)=-1\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}n\right)=-\infty$$

Comment: The first step could lead to false conclusions in other scenarios, since the sequence $(n)$ doesn't converge. Therefore I'd be careful with this sort of argument.

Comment: Yes of course, but this is the right answer, I've also checked it in Mathematica